# A limit that exists strongly in Sobolev space $H^s$ and weakly in $H^{s+1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

In his paper  'Nonstationary flows of viscous and ideal fluids in $\Bbb{R}^3$' Kato mentioned the following: a limit that exists strongly in $H^{m-1}$ and weakly in $H^{m}$ what is explicitly the meaning of that convergence? is it simply the following:
$$\lim\limits_{\nu\to 0}\|u_\nu-u_0\|_{H^{m-1}}=0~~\mbox{and} ~\lim\limits_{\nu\to0}\langle u_\nu-u,\phi\rangle_{H^m}=0,$$
where $\phi$ is a test function (well localized and a regular enough function)

*Kato, Tosio*, [**Nonstationary flows of viscous and ideal fluids in $R^3$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(72)90003-1), J. Funct. Anal. 9, 296-305 (1972). [ZBL0229.76018](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0229.76018).

Comment: Yes, it should mean something like that.